# Moodle: web service call to get assignments under course

Tags: php, rest, moodle, moodle-api

I have an application where I need to fetch records from Moodle using the core Web Service API.

I am receiving courses and categories with the following API calls:

```
core_course_get_courses
core_course_get_categories
```

But I am not able to find the right parameter (or maybe my implementation was wrong) for

```
mod_assign_get_assignments
```

I tried as below

```
http://moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wsfunction=mod_assign_get_assignments&moodlewsrestformat=json&wstoken=token&courseids[0]=27
```

Can anyone have any idea how I can get assignments from a course?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following method used to fetch records under a course in Moodle

```
http://moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wsfunction=mod_assign_get_assignments&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=core_course_get_contents&moodlewsrestformat=json&courseid=
```

Comment: This only works if the WebService user is enrolled tothat specific course , otherwise it returns {"courses":[],"warnings":[{"item":"course","itemid":3,"warningcode":"2","message":"User is not enrolled or does not have requested capability"}]}

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly I was looking for :D

Answer (score 0):

Your command is not working mostly because your web services user is not enrolled in the course. Go to course settings and enroll the user.

This works for me:

```
https://your.moodlesite.com/webservice/rest/server.php?wsfunction=mod_assign_get_assignments&wstoken=5a67fb5d660a987a5705a4b47c0ad1fa&moodlewsrestformat=json&courseids[0]=3
```

The last parameter 'courseids' is not necessary.